Excel 2010 formula to show earliest date & value from table (list of dates) that is after a reference date assigned to each unique ID
I have this formula that isn't quite correct.
The best example of the issue is in cell C5:
=IF(MAX(IF(F5:F15=$A5,G5:G15))<$B5,"",SUMIFS(H5:H15,F5:F15,$A5,G5:G15,MIN(IF(F5:F15=$A5,G5:G15))))

It is finding the earliest value, but not the earliest value AFTER the reference date in column B. It shows the value as 0.1, but I need it to show as 2. because this is on or after the reference date.
I also need the same for the date in column D, which will be aligned to the adjacent value, so that the left table in columns C and D, show the earliest date and value from the right table, where the ID is matched and are after each reference date for each ID.
Is this possible with a formula?


Column F to G:



id
eventdate
value




1
3/8/2024
200


3
3/5/2024



3
2/5/2021
300


25
7/16/2024
72


25
4/22/2024
50


7825
7/17/2024



7825
7/16/2024
2


7825
7/15/2024
0.9


7825
6/17/2024
0.7


7825
9/6/2005
0.1


23250
4/8/2024
0.2



Columns A To D



ID
REFERENCE DATE
VALUE
EVENTDATE




1
3/8/2024




3
3/7/2024




25
4/22/2024




7825
7/16/2024




23250
4/8/2024






That's great for the value. Thank you. However, it isn't working for the date when I use =INDEX($G$2:$G$12,MATCH(1,1/((H$2:H$12<=$B5)*($A5=$F$2:$F$12)),0)). This is showing the latest date i.e. 17/07/2024. What have I missed?

Please try using the following formula:


• For Values:
=INDEX($H$2:$H$12,
 MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS(B2-$G$2:$G$12)/(A2=$F$2:$F$12),1),
 ABS(B2-$G$2:$G$12)/(A2=$F$2:$F$12),0))


• For Dates:
=INDEX($G$2:$G$12,
 MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS(B2-$G$2:$G$12)/(A2=$F$2:$F$12),1),
 ABS(B2-$G$2:$G$12)/(A2=$F$2:$F$12),0))



Perfect. Thank you

Could you tell me what part of the formula determines that it finds the EARLIEST value or date after the reference date and id match? i.e. what would I change to get the latest (rather than the earliest) date and value? With regards to this formula=INDEX(G$2:G$12,MATCH(1,1/(($G$2:$G$12<=$B2)*($A2=$F$2:$F$12)),0))

I think I've worked it out, by changing the >= to <= in ($G$2:$G$12>=$B5)

Sorry I don't think this is still correct. If I change the 1st date in the right table assigned to id 1 to 27/03/2024, it shows as #N/A. Yet this date is still after the reference date (08/03/2024) and is the earliest date being that there is only 1 date. Sorry to be a pain :(

@BradS I highly doubt it is still working on my end! Check_Here

@BradS can you show me a screenshot how it is not working on your end. Like I have shown it is working, so i can visualize the issue on your end

@BradS try using the updated formula!

Ahh I didn't see that you had updated the formula, which works great now. So if I wanted the latest value after the reference date, what part of the formula would I need to change?

When I changed it 14, it reverted back to my original problem in that id 7825 shows the 0.1 value dated 06/09/2005. I was looking to get the blank value and date of 17/07/2024

Wait sorry i missed one thing

When I changed the - to a + it worked and showed the latest i.e. ABS(B5+$G$2:$G$12). Whole formula: =INDEX($H$2:$H$12,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(B5+$G$2:$G$12)/(A5=$F$2:$F$12),1),ABS(B5+$G$2:$G$12)/(A5=$F$2:$F$12),0))

Sounds Good, !!!

Thank you for this. It was driving me mad and I would never have come up with that formula. There are some very clearer people out there. THANKFULLY!

But have you made it 14 before making it + from -, otherwise it will give wrong result again!

Yes changing it to 14 and using a + gives me the latest after the reference date, and 15 with a - gives me the earliest after the reference date

Great two questions solved with one answers!
